# Browsers, other windows crashing Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Tags: chromium, browser

I use a Dell Precision M4800 with Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS.

And I am having an issue where any browser I use (Chromium, Firefox) constantly crashes. Typically it just goes to the screen on Chromium,

> Aw Snap! Something went wrong while displaying this webpage.

and similar messages. Occasionally I'll have all of my windows crash (close completely). I have ran a memory test and it appeared to be fine (not an expert).

Comment: Please first fully update your system then reboot and retry...

Comment: sudo apt-get update and then sudo apt-get upgrade The first comment was not wrong but lacked any actual help. Run these two commands after the first finishes run the second this will make sure you are up-to date before any more trouble shooting.

Comment: I followed those steps but it still says Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS