# Upgrading from 20.04.2 Errors Unmet Dependencies

Tags: upgrade

I am trying to upgrade from 20.04.2. I get this error:

```
user@user:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-81-generic but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

When running apt --fix-broken install I get this error:

```
(Reading database ... 322814 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-81-generic_5.4.0-81.91_amd64.d
eb ...
Unpacking linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-81-generic (5.4.0-81.91) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: compressed data
 is corrupt
dpkg-deb: error: <decompress> subprocess returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-modules-extra-5.4.0
-81-generic_5.4.0-81.91_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './lib/modules/5.4.0-81-generic/kernel/net/bluet
ooth/bluetooth.ko' to '/lib/modules/5.4.0-81-generic/kernel/net/bluetooth/blueto
oth.ko.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-81-generic_5.4.0-81.91_amd64.
deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I am trying to upgrade to fix this problem as no one will advise until I upgrade: [Browsers, other windows crashing Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1359807/browsers-other-windows-crashing-ubuntu-20-04-2-lts)

Comment: Hard drive issues? cannot copy extracted data for './lib/modules/5.4.0-81-generic/kernel/net/bluet
ooth/bluetooth.ko' to '/lib/modules/5.4.0-81-generic/kernel/net/bluetooth/blueto
oth.ko.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream

Answer (score 0):

The issue is:

```
Preparing to unpack .../linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-81-generic_5.4.0-81.91_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-81-generic (5.4.0-81.91) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: compressed data is corrupt
```

Everything else is a cascade caused by your corrupt package.

The process to fix has two steps:

1. Manually delete the corrupt package.

   Packages are stored in /var/cache/apt/archives.

   You know the package name. It's in your output.

   Example: `sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-81-generic_5.4.0-81.91_amd64.deb`
2. Let apt re-download the package

   Example: `sudo apt-get upgrade`